# Problem with my Proof that Countable Additivity Implies Countable Subadditivity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> Show that if $\mu$ is a measure with domain $\mathscr{A}$ and $E_n \in \mathscr{A}$ for each positive integer $n$, then
> $$\mu\left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \right)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_n).$$

I know this is a routine exercise, but I'm confused if the proof I came up with is correct, as it differs from the ones I've found in textbooks.

*My proof:*

Without loss of generality, order the $E_n$'s so that $E_n \subset
E_{n+1}$. Set $F_1 = \emptyset$ and $F_n=E_n \setminus E_{n-1}$ for
$n>1$ so that $E_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} F_k$. Then $$\begin{align}
\mu\left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \right) = \mu\left (
\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k \right)  & = \mu\left ( \emptyset \cup
\bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty}F_k \right) \\ & = \mu \left (
\bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty} E_k \setminus E_{k-1} \right ) \\ & \leq \mu
\left( \bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty} E_k \right ) \\ & = \mu \left(
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \right ) \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\mu(E_n) \end{align}$$
My primary issue is — am I allowed to order the $E_n$'s in that way without loss of generality? And if they are nested like that, how can the $E_n$'s be pairwise disjoint, which is necessary based on my textbook's definition of countable additivity. Many thanks.

Comment: You *do* lose generality by considering only the sequences $E_n$ that are totally ordered. For instance, you are not considering the sequences $E_n$ such that there are $k,h$ such that $E_k\nsubseteq E_h$ and $E_h\nsubseteq E_k$.

Comment: AH, I see. Since the $E_n$'s are pairwise disjoint is it true that $E_n=E_n \setminus E_{n-1}$ then?

Comment: The $E_n$s are also not "pairwise disjoint". They are just an arbitrary sequence of measurable sets.

Comment: For instance, consider the intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with $E_1=[0,1]$, $E_2=[3/4,5/4]$, $E_3=[9/8,13/8]$, etc: $E_n$ has length $1/2^{n-1}$, and overlaps with $E_{n-1}$ on the rightmost $1/2^{n+1}$ part of the interval.

Comment: You are assuming that your  measure satisfies countable additivity. So if you have *some* countable collection of pairwise disjoint meausrable sets $F_1,F_2,\ldots$, then you know that $\mu(\cup F_i) = \sum \mu(F_i)$. You want to prove that is satisfies subadditivity, so you take *any* countable collection $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of measurable sets and you want to prove that $\mu(\cup E_i) \leq \sum \mu(E_i)$. You do not assume the $E_i$ are pairwise disjoint, and you cannot assume they are nested or anything like that.

Comment: Thank you so much that clears up everything, Arturo!

Comment: the short version is that if they  were pairwise disjoiont it would be equality.  Losing pairwise disjointment can only make the measure of the union smaller than the sum,  since you might be losing some measure of overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not generally rearrange the class of sets $E_n$ s.t. $E_{n_k}\subset E_{n_{k+1}},\; (\forall k)(k\in Z)$

example:
$E_n=[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$

in Borel sigma-Algebra in $[0,1]$.

$E_{n+1}=[\frac{1}{n+2}, \frac{1}{n+1}]$
$E_n\cap E_{n+1}=\{\frac{1}{n+1}\}\ne\emptyset$

Yet there exists no rearrangement that satisifies inclusion by definition of these sets.

Thus, to prove that:

$\mu(\cup_{n}{E_n})\leq\sum_n{\mu(E_n)}$

it is needed to use the axiom of monotonicity.
$A\subseteq B\implies \mu(A)\leq \mu(B)$

Hence, define:

$F_1=E_1\\
F_2=E_2-E_1\\
F_n=E_n-\cup_{k=1}^{n-1}{E_k}$

So

$(\forall n)(\mu(F_n)\leq\mu(E_n))$

Thus:

$\mu(\cup_n{E_n})=\mu(\cup_n{F_n})=\sum{\mu(F_n)}\leq\sum{\mu(E_n)}$